# SQlite: транзакция не срабатывает при клике

Tags: sqlite, javascript

```
function addObject(tx) 
         { 
         tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Routes (id_object) VALUES (10)');     
         tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Routes", [], function (tx, result) { alert(result.rows.item(0)['id_object'])  },function (tx, error) {alert('Неудача');} )
         }
function querySuccess(tx, results) 
{
$('#a').append('<span id = "click0">Пройти <br />позже</span>');
$('#click0').click(function(){alert('сработало!');db.transaction(addObject, errorCB);});
}
```

Появляется вопрос. как передать параметр наверх за пределы функции? Чтобы вместо values 10 можно было вписать переменную.  callback?